# Does the file need to be closed after modifying with 'sed'?

Tags: windows, bash, shell

I have a shell script which contains a `sed` command that does the insertion into an existing file:

```
sed -i "/<test name=\"test-$NUMBER\">/i $NEW_TEST_SUITE" test.xml
```

After running this shell script, I opened the file `test.xml` in Notepad++, and there is indeed a new line being inserted before:

```
<test name="test-XXXX">
```

However, when I tried to do a pretty print (by clicking <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>) and save that file, it popped up an alert saying:

> Please check if this file is opened in another program

So I was thinking could that be caused by modifying the file while not closing it? Do I need to close the file after using `sed`? If so, could you tell me what the command is since I've searched online but didn't find anything regarding this? (my platform is Windows 7)

Comment: What version of sed are you using?  You say Win7, but sed is not part of Win7.  Are you using MinGW?  Cygwin?  Other? Also, there is no `/i` modifier either, since I'm assuming you are using gnu, it would be `/I`.

Comment: @Adrian, Hi, I'm using Cygwin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. When sed exits, the file is closed.

This is probably a permissions issue. Verify that your Windows user has write access to the file.

If it's on a Windows partition, try running Notepad++ as administrator. If it's on a Linux shared fs, try `chmod`.

Comment: The error msg `Please check if this file is opened in another program` would indicate that the file is open, not that there is a permission problem.

Comment: Also, if the permissions are incorrect, you might want to look at what user you are running the shell script under since sed was able to modify the file but Notepad++ couldn't.  Otherwise you may have problems cropping up elsewhere.  Unless required, you shouldn't be running with administrator privileges.

Answer (score 2):

No, sed does not keep files open.  Once the script has completed, all open files are then closed.

Try using [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to find what process has the file open.  Use Ctrl-F to find an open handle that is attached to the file you are having problems with.